# Злоумышленники через wi fi могут перехватить Cookie. А один сайт может перехватить cookie второго сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование, cookie, браузер, webbrowser

*В  некоторых источниках   я читала что один сайт не может  иметь доступ к Cookies другого сайта и что сайт может получить доступ только к информации которую он сам разместил на жестком диске .
А в других источниках  написано что браузер с несколькими открытыми вкладками  представляет собой единый сеанс. Когда мы переходим от вкладка вкладки передаем информацию о своей истории посещений другим веб сайтам.
Если мы посещали веб сайт на котором  создали идентификатор входа и если во время сеанса у нас открыты другие вкладки наши cookie файлы могут раскрывать нашу конкретную информацию другим сторонам.*

**Как можно понять все это и какой из этих информации соответствует реальности ?**

Comment: Вкладки от одного сайта могут читать одинаковые свои куки. Другим вкладкам с другими сайтами эти куки не доступны.

Comment: Все что написано во второй части после слов "А в других источниках" почти полный бред. Что это за источники такие, хотелось бы дословно прочитать что именно там написано. Может там речь идет например о вкладках с одним и тем же сайтом или скажем о вкладках, на которых открыты сайты, включающие в свою страницу скрипты с других сайтов (и отдающие себе отчет в том, что они делают)

Comment: @Mike вот  источник                                                                                                    https://cookie-script.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-third-party-cookies.html?fbclid=IwAR1PemvnP2m_O-LRD7iYrbhV1IGxXcj_kWEUvXJuLvL3laGEHA_tPe_rc3Q

Comment: @Mike а это часть  про обмен информации между вкладками  :
"  You’re unintentionally creating a “trail of crumbs.” Most web users don’t realize that a browser window with multiple tabs open constitutes a single “session.” As you move from tab to tab, you are unwittingly relaying information about your web visit history to other websites and parties. And, closing the web browser doesn’t always eliminate the cookies your computer stores following the session. "

Comment: @Mike и это тоже:                                                                                                                             That seemingly random email isn’t so random. Let’s say you’ve visited a website where you have created a login ID. They likely have your name, email address, and possibly even your telephone number and street address. If the website uses 3rd-party cookies, or you have other tabs open during your session, your cookies may be revealing your contact information to other parties in order to send you SPAM.

Comment: Ну да, бред чистой воды. Так обычно пугали в начале 0х годов куками, давно такого не видел. Ну да, конечно они позволяют следить за вами. Только совершенно иными способами, не нарушающими никакую безопасность. Большинство сайтов используют всякие системы подсчета рейтинга от гугла или яндекса и другие подобные и да, их куки поэтому есть практически на всех страницах (по желанию создателей этих сайтов) и да, у себя конечно они собирают информацию посещений. Но только если явно их разработчик сайта у себя не разместил, то никакая другая вкладка данных не получит

Comment: Лучше почитайте нормальную документацию по работе кук и других средств идентификации, ну и поэкспериментируйте сами, с несколькими доменами и куками от них